# Javascript documentation block comments

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting to document some Javascript code that I've written and I have a question.  Looking through my vendor directory to see how the 3rd party packages do it, I've noticed that many of them (eg. jQuery, Modernizr, fancyBox) start with a comment block like :

```
/*!
 * package name
```

Where does this style of comment come from and how should it look?  Is it a Bower thing?

The consensus on the web seems to be to use JSDoc style comments which all seem to start with /** not /*! .  So what are those vendors following?

Comment: many IDE's use use it also to autocomplete documentation. It is also used in exports for documentation